# Flatten PowerPoint Accent Colors?

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint, diacritics, flatten

I have developed an XML template to define custom accent colors within PowerPoint.  Basically my own design template color schemes.  About a dozen of them.  Here's the problem.  When I share my PowerPoint file with someone on a Mac platform that doesn't have access to my custom XML files (I have provided them to them but somehow they aren't "found") the colors will re-map to whatever the accent colors are defined as on their platform.  Usually very ugly and wonky looking.  Anyway, I was wondering if it was possible to write an Add-On or VBA script or something that could essentially "flatten" the accent colors so that Design Themes will no longer affect them anymore.  I want my XML files to work during the development of my slides but then not work when I get ready to share the file.  Is this doable?  Anyone? I can further clarify this question if need be.  Also if there was a way to reverse it again that would be excellent too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Colors in PPT can be scheme/theme colors or they can be straight RGB colors.  Theme colors are essentially indexes into the current theme ... Color1 = whatever RGB value's assigned to the first color in the theme, and changing the theme will change everything that's assigned theme color 1.

RGB colors are locked in ... what you're calling flattened.  Changes to the theme won't affect them.

In theory it's possible to go through every shape in the presentation and every bit of text, and every element in every chart and assign the equivalent RGB color to the theme colors, but it's not at all simple.  If you have a very limited range of shapes, no charts etc., it shouldn't be TOO difficult though.